# tRestClient Talend with dynamic URL and paramters from DB returns null

Tags: json, postgresql, rest, dictionary, talend

I'm trying to use Talend from a REST web service and by passing parameters that come from a DB.

I̶ ̶a̶m̶ ̶t̶r̶y̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶l̶i̶n̶k̶ ̶t̶P̶o̶s̶g̶r̶e̶s̶q̶l̶I̶n̶p̶u̶t̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶p̶o̶n̶e̶n̶e̶t̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶t̶R̶e̶s̶t̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶p̶o̶n̶e̶n̶t̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶s̶e̶e̶ ̶h̶o̶w̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶p̶a̶s̶s̶ ̶D̶B̶ ̶r̶o̶w̶s̶ ̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶U̶R̶L̶,̶ ̶b̶u̶t̶ ̶i̶t̶s̶ ̶s̶e̶e̶m̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶t̶R̶E̶S̶T̶ ̶d̶o̶e̶s̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶a̶c̶c̶e̶p̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶n̶g̶s̶ ̶l̶i̶k̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶.̶

T̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶w̶a̶h̶t̶ ̶I̶ ̶d̶i̶d̶ ̶u̶n̶t̶i̶l̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶t̶i̶m̶e̶ ̶:̶

̶t̶P̶o̶s̶g̶r̶e̶s̶q̶l̶I̶n̶p̶u̶t̶ ̶x̶x̶x̶x̶x̶x̶ ̶t̶R̶E̶S̶T̶ ̶-̶-̶-̶>̶ ̶t̶E̶x̶t̶r̶a̶c̶t̶J̶S̶O̶N̶F̶i̶e̶l̶d̶s̶ ̶-̶-̶-̶>̶ ̶t̶M̶a̶p̶ ̶-̶-̶-̶>̶ ̶t̶P̶o̶s̶g̶r̶e̶s̶q̶l̶O̶u̶t̶p̶u̶t̶

I verified that the DB component returns data below:

[image]

I updated the job as this:

[image]

The Schema of tRESTClient is :

[image]

And I used globalMap to pass the values from the database:

The used URL is : "URL/search/"+ (String)globalMap.get("row1.hashtag")

But when I see the results, I found it used the "null" value to request the server.

Comment: Could you include your component configurations as screenshots? Also you will have to elaborate on *use many keywords from DB*. What is the required mapping of DB values onto REST values exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I needed is to use a tFlowToIterate component to iterate each row, so that we will able to access the input data extracted from DB and set a dynamic URL.

For example as I have before, the job must look like this :

BBin --main(row1)--> tFlowToITerate --iterate--> tREST ---> tExtractJSONFields ---> tMap ---> DBout

On tRest, we can set a dynamic URL like:

"SOME_URL/otherpath/"+(String)globalMap.get("row1.columnName")